# What coin/pendant is this and is it worth any money?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome, ancient-greece

[image][image]

This was found a long time ago by my neighbour who has now passed it on to me. It has NAX IOIA on the coin with what I believe to be a kings or gods face on one side and some grapes and vines on the other.

Comment: It's difficult to gauge size from the picture, how large is it? The hole suggests that it's been used as jewelry (although it might not have been created for that purpose).

Comment: Where was this found (i.e. what country/region)?

Comment: It looks like a modern tourist souvenir. They're usually something like 6 - 8 cm or so across, and very loosely based on the design of coins like [this silver Drachm](https://www.acsearch.info/search.html?id=997055) from Naxos.

Comment: I have the same medallion made out of brass with a silver coloured heavy chain. It was my mother's and she got it in the 60s or 70s. Not sure where in Europe.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like a modern tourist souvenir. The inscription actually reads *NAX IOIA*.

These medallions are usually something like 6 - 8 cm across, and are very loosely based on the design of coins like this [silver Drachm](https://www.acsearch.info/search.html?id=997055) from Naxos:

[image: Drachm]

The original shows the head of the god Dionysus on the obverse, and a bunch of grapes on stalk with two leaves on the reverse. The inscription on the reverse was originally NAC ION (which is perhaps rather less-recognisable to tourists), and the difference in the quality of the images between the original coin and the modern souvenir is very noticeable.

Your medallion is probably cast, rather than hammered, although I can't make out enough of the edge detail from your photograph to be certain. I've seen medallions like that sold online from time-to-time. They usually sell for a few pounds Sterling.

---

**EDIT**: [This gilded example](http://www.toplicit.com/detail.asp?id=1936232) (which was actually 57mm in diameter) sold for 25,000 Hungarian Florint (about £7.00 GB at current exchange rates) in 2013.